# Unable to resolve 'System.IO.Pipelines (>= 0.1.0-e170328-3)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.1' at dotnet restore command

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, azure, asp.net-core

We have an ASP.NET Core project built on Azure Hosted agents. A few days ago, for unknown reason the builds on Hosted Agent started to fail at dotnet restore command with the messages:

> Unable to resolve 'System.IO.Pipelines (>= 0.1.0-e170328-3)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.1'.
>         Unable to resolve 'System.Text.Encodings.Web.Utf8 (>= 0.1.0-e170328-3)' for '.NETCoreApp,Version=v1.1.1'.

The build in Visual Studio works fine. Initially the solution was created in Visual Studio 2015, then while trying to fix the issue, I converted it to Visual Studio 2017, but result was still the same.
Does anyone know a reason why this might happen and where to look for solution?

Comment: `System.IO.Pipelines` and `System.Text.Encodings.Web.Utf8` ar part of Corefx Lab. These are experimental packages, you won't find them in nuget.org. Perhaps you forgot to add [the myget source](https://dotnet.myget.org/feed/dotnet-corefxlab/package/nuget/System.IO.Pipelines.File)  to your project? `https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-corefxlab/` or `https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-corefxlab/api/v3/index.json`

Comment: Yes, adding https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-corefxlab/ helped. Thanks very much! Please add it as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.IO.Pipelines` and `System.Text.Encodings.Web.Utf8` namespaces are part of experimental projects hosted on the [CoreFX Lab repo](https://github.com/dotnet/corefxlab). These packages can't be found on nuget.org.

To use and restore these packages you have to add https://dotnet.myget.org/F/dotnet-corefxlab/ to your nuget sources

Answer (score -2):

Not all nuget packages are completely migrated to support .NET Core. However, you can target multiple versions of .Net Core app like this:

```
"frameworks": {
    "net452": {
      "frameworkAssemblies": {
        "System.Net.Http": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Xml": "4.0.0.0",
        "System.Xml.Linq": "4.0.0.0"
      }
    }
  }
```

You can search the various supported package names for diffrent versions [here](https://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/): https://packagesearch.azurewebsites.net/

Read More: 
[How to Manage Package Dependency Versions for .NET Core 1.0](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/tutorials/managing-package-dependency-versions)

Comment: umm, that is the json format for projects, it is not supported anymore.

Comment: The complaint is about specific experimental packages. It's not related to .NET Core versions or the project format